# iterrows() loop is only reading last value and only modifying first row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `test`. My goal is to search in the column `t1` for specific strings, and if it matches exactly a specific string, put that string in the next column over called `t1_selected`. Only thing is, I can't get `iterrows()` to go over the entire dataframe, and to report results in respective rows.

```
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    if any(['ABCD_T1w_MPR_vNav_passive' in row['t1']]):
        #x = ast.literal_eval(row['t1'])
        test.loc[i, 't1_selected'] = str(['ABCD_T1w_MPR_vNav_passive'])
```

I am only trying to get `ABCD_T1w_MPR_vNav_passive` to be in the 4th row under the `t1_selected`, while all the other rows will have `not found`. The first entry in `t1_selected` is from the last row under `t1` which I didn't include in the screenshot because the dataframe has over 200 rows.

I tried to initialize an empty list to append output of

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(row['t1'])
```

to see if I can put `x` in there, but the same issue occurred.

Is there anything I am missing?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    if any(['ABCD_T1w_MPR_vNav_passive' in row['t1']]):
        #x = ast.literal_eval(row['t1'])
        test.loc[index, 't1_selected'] = str(['ABCD_T1w_MPR_vNav_passive'])
```

Where `index` is the row its written to.  With `i` it was not changing